# How and where to initialize UITabBarControllerDelegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift

I have a `UITabBarController` linked to 4 `UIViewController` each embedded in a `NavigationViewController`.

I need to check if when one of these view controllers is currently selected, and the user clicks the same tab bar item for the same view, it will trigger an unwind segue action.

So I think I need to add a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` but when I tried to add it to the `UITabBarController` class in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
let tabBarDel: UITabBarControllerDelegate = UITabBarControllerDelegate()
```

I see the following error:
'`UITabBarControllerDelegate`' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible `initializers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended the view controller class with UITabBarControllerDelegate. In the viewDidLoad() method I used self.tabBarController?.delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController is a protocol, not a class. You can't instantiate a protocol. You need to create your own implementation of the protocol.